# is it possible to delete only one of the returns from the Jmeter result tree? Type specify?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I know it is possible to delete the entire Jmeter result tree, through the code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.JMeterGUIComponent;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.Clearable;

log.info("Clearing All ...");

guiPackage = GuiPackage.getInstance();

guiPackage.getMainFrame().clearData();
for (JMeterTreeNode node : guiPackage.getTreeModel().getNodesOfType(Clearable.class)) {
    JMeterGUIComponent guiComp = guiPackage.getGui(node.getTestElement());
    if (guiComp instanceof Clearable){
        Clearable item = (Clearable) guiComp;
        try {
            item.clearData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Can't clear: "+node+" "+guiComp, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

but I didn't want to delete the entire result tree, only the returns that returned with status == 500. Because my api returns 500 until the callback is available for consultation, when it finds the callback it returns "success", so while the api keeps retrying, these retries show up as an error in the report,but in fact the callback has not returned yet, when it returns the api returns the callback and is successful. I would like to remove these requests from the report, which are retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys. First, thanks for the answers, I ended up giving up on the idea of ​​removing the result from the tree and looking for a way to modify the way that result is presented.

I made a beanShell assertion, so that if Status==500, it would return "Success" in the result tree:

[BeanShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMsjo.png)

I also made it so that if it were a new attempt the name displayed in the results tree would indicate this, leaving the api name mutable depending on the return:

[api name = variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nggqV.png)

and I have this logic:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

//process main sample
if (${status} == 500) {
    SampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_name", "API_FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY");
```

I will configure the answers in the other conditions, but I believe that this way I will be able to solve my problem because the new attempts no longer appear as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with following code to ignore the test results when the response code is **500**

```
if (prev.getResponseCode()=="500"){
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

[image]

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult (if any)

API documentation for prev variable ([SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without modifying JMeter source code or heavily using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). In any case the answer will not fit here.

In general:

1. You should be using JMeter GUI only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to test execution you should [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. [You should not be using listeners during test execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/) as they don't add any value, just consume valuable resources, all the necessary information is stored in [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)
3. There is [Filter Results plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which allows removing the "unwanted" data from the .jtl results file
4. You can also (as well) generate the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the .jtl results file, the Dashboard has its own responses [filtering facilities](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements)